# Oracle substr before a specific character

Tags: sql, oracle, substr

I am trying to obtain the string before '_' character, I am using:

```
select SUBSTR('Lorik_1', 1, INSTR('Lorik_1','_') - 1) from dual;
```

This works fine for this case, but I want to modify it to work with values which don't have '_'.

```
select SUBSTR('Lorik', 1, INSTR('Lorik','_') - 1) from dual;
```

In this case it will output NULL and this does not work for me!

How can I modify this query so it will output 'Lorik', but when '_' is present it will remove it and the string after it.

P.S. I cannot use Case when statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option, using `REGEXP_SUBSTR`:

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT 'Lorik_1' AS col FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Lorik' FROM dual
)

SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (col, '^[^_]+')
FROM yourTable;
```

This outputs `Lorik` for both columns, see the demo here:

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
select regexp_substr('Lorik','[^_]+') 
  from dual;
```

including `[^_]+` pattern only.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8132fe634c7abf1b372124868f4a8605)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `regexp_replace()` to trim everthing after the first underscore (included):

```
regexp_replace(mycol, '_.*$', '')
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b409006709eb666cc9e44d8e71569764)**:

```
with t as (
    select 'lorik_1' as mycol from dual 
    union all select 'lorik' from dual
)
select regexp_replace(mycol, '_.*$', '') from t;
```

```
| REGEXP_REPLACE(MYCOL,'_.*$','') |
| :------------------------------ |
| lorik                           |
| lorik                           |
```